# Is it acceptable to use code that overflows but gives the correct result?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

I want to subtract two user-supplied integers, and store the resulting range length. I obviously can't store it as an integer, as subtracting `int.MaxValue` and `int.MinValue` for example will overflow an int.

I wrote this :

```
uint rangeLength = (uint)max - (uint)min
```

It works in every case, but you can see that the cast will oveflow the `uint` type when one of the two integers is negative. However, this line gives the correct result.

This seems to do the same, doing two more operations, but without overflowing :

```
uint rangeLength = ((uint)max + int.MaxValue) - ((uint)min + int.MaxValue);
```

Is it acceptable to use the first line it in my code, or is it too confusing ? Should I use the second one just so that it doesn't seem like an error ?

Comment: why can't you store it a `long` type then?

Comment: Actually you can even store it as an `int`, just make sure to interpret it correctly later.

Comment: `uint` and `long` are _different_.

Comment: Yes it is ok.  I've done that lots time when design logic circuits in hardware and simulating results with a c/C# application.  It would help if you added a comment so it is not confusing to reader.   You code make perfect sense to me since I have a BSEE.  The microprocessor is designed to work with signed and unsigned numbers and when doing math operations the overflow underflow bits should be ignored.

Comment: @YdobEmos, really? why not refer the MSDN doc instead of questioning me

Comment: @YdobEmos, *it's an alias for Int64* ... no wrong again. `Int64` coresponds to `long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works in every case, then I think readability is the only thing you need to worry about.

You seem to have named your variables correctly - `rangeLength`. And you wrote that it is equal to `max - min`, so people probably will understand what you are doing. If you named the result `a` or something like that, then it's bad. If you are really worried, make it a method and abstract away the implementation details:

```
public uint RangeBetween(int max, int min) {
    return (uint)max - (uint)min;
}

uint rangeLength = RangeBetween(max, min);
```

Comment: am still bit confused as to what OP asking. Is he asking about overflow on math operation? or is he looking for suggestion?

Comment: The last sentences in the question is exactly what the OP is asking, right? "Is it acceptable to use the first line it in my code, or is it too confusing ? Should I use the second one just so that it doesn't seem like an error ?" @Rahul

Comment: Yes, this last sentence is what I'm asking. I had to wait a bit for SO to allow me to accept your answer. Thank you.